# Rewarded video ads Chartboost - Unity 5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, chartboost

Am trying to integrate video rewarded ads in my game how can I show video ads and handle if the ad is successfully shown to reward the player ?
I couldn't find any thing about that on Chartboost docs it only says

```
Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocation.MainMenu);
```

But how to handle success or failure from ad and where to add the code to reward the player if the ad is successfully shown ?

Comment: I am using FusePowered - FuseSdk for show ads. You should use it too. It is so simple. You can check if the ad is successfully shown with adwillclose in this document. https://wiki.fusepowered.com/index.php?title=Unity

Comment: Why not use the ADS solution provided by Unity? It's called UnityADS, I'm using in my game and is very easy to integrate it. https://unity3d.com/pt/services/ads

Answer (score 0):

Add in `OnEnable()` function this code

```
`Chartboost.didCompleteRewardedVideo += didCompleteRewar;`
```

After this `void didCompleteRewardedVideo(CBLocation location, int reward)` will be called if Reward video is completed. For more information you can check this page: https://answers.chartboost.com/en-us/child_article/unity-3